Grouping column and the result will be displayed horizontally
I'm trying to work out how to get the result horizontally using group by and family column values should be displayed horizontally.
I want to find the itemids that used familys.
CREATE TABLE Table1
([ITEMID] int, Family (15))

;
INSERT INTO Table1
([ITEMID], [Family])
VALUES
('1234', 'F1'),
('1234', 'F2'),
('1234', 'F3')
('12345', 'F1'),
('12345', 'F2'),
('12345', 'F4')
('123457', 'F1'),
('123457', 'F2')
('123457', 'F3')
('223457', 'F1')
('223457', 'F2')
('423458', 'F8')

;
Expected result
ITEMID--FAMILY
1234----F1,F2,F3
12345---F1,F2,F4
123457--F1,F2,F3
223457--F1,F2,
423458--F8


Hi you could use the GROUP_CONCAT.
SELECT ITEMID, GROUP_CONCAT(Family ORDER BY Family) AS FAMILY
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ITEMID;


I tried to use the group_group but its not working in presto dbeaver. the error say group _concat is not registered. Is there any alternative code to be use. thanks

using this code and its working. array_join(array_agg(family), ',') as model. my question is how can i sort the value of raay_join

Try this:  array_join(array_agg(family ORDER BY family), ',')
